# Restore from Time Machine backup stalls on disk password request, won't accept true password

Tags: backup, time-machine, password, filevault

I have a machine whose drive became corrupt. I erased the drive and installed a basic system on it. I'm now trying to restore it to its previous state from the last Time Machine backup.

I had been backing the machine up to a NAS drive--which I was unable to restore from—so I copied the sparsebundle to a USB drive. Then I tried using Migration Assistant. That fails, saying "The selected source cannot be used for migration. Volume does not contain an installation of OS X or macOS."

So then I booted into Recovery Mode and directed it to restore from the USB drive and it correctly sees the Time Machine backups. I select the most recent one and it asks for the Time Machine password (which it accepts) and then finally asks me to unlock the "Untitled" drive on the laptop (it is encrypted). But when I type in the password for that drive, it rejects the password!

If I immediately quit the restore and reboot the machine, it once again asks for the disk password. I then give it the same password I did in the previous step, and it comes right up.

Any ideas what's going on? I am definitely providing the correct password to unlock the disk in this final step before restore (it's all the same password for me, from Time Machine to the disk to my account).

Comment: I bypassed the problem by erasing the laptop drive via Disk Utility in Recovery Mode, reformatting as APFS (without encryption), then going back to Time Machine System Restore (again, in recovery mode). Then everything was as before, except when I specfied the Untitled drive as the destination, it didn't stall since it didn't require a password. Interestingly, as this point, it started to restore but also said that it was turning File Vault off (and that I'd have to turn it back on after restore). So not a solution, but a workaround.